# SSIS: Dynamic SQL Query Expression VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I am building a SSIS package that loops through a folder and retrieves the SQL query from each file in turn. I then set an Expression equal this SQL query and pass it through a variable to a DataFlow that contains an ODBC Query (Source) and Flat File (CSV) destination.

I initially set the SQLVariable to a SQL statement to initialize otherwise the ODBC query complains. When I execute, I get a VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error. I presume it is because the first file I read has a different SQL statement then the one I initially set and since I change the query SSIS is throwing metadata error.

How to get around this error. I have over 50 SQL files of different SQL queries that must be executed in turn.

Thanks

Comment: My approach would be to convert the files to stored procedures.  Then write another one that executes them all in the proper order.  Call that last one with your SSIS package.

Comment: Currently, the ODBC is pulling the data from a Progress database/server. We are currently using a LinkedServer Object with SPROCS as you mentioned but executing these queries and storing the data takes over 4 hours (I/O, data volumes). I want to move everything to SSIS. Pull all the data into csv files and then either use a data flow to write to tables and/or in some cases use bcp for very large datasets.

Comment: @user1082748 : While executing odbc to csv, try `delay-validation property = true`, `validate external metadata = false` for both src and destination. This is risky, but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat, this works.